# Unknown custom element on downloaded template using Vue

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I'll try to be short but clear.

I downloaded a template of Vuejs for admin (from [here](https://www.creative-tim.com/product/vue-light-bootstrap-dashboard)), but I am having troubles modifying it. I created one new component but I can't use it because is not being recognized. The console error says:

> Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

I don't know why is this happening because I am importing the component as every other one. Look the script code in the father component.

```js
  import LTable from 'src/components/UIComponents/Tables/Table.vue'
  import ETable from 'src/components/UIComponents/Tables/EditableTable.vue' //THIS IS MY NEW COMPONENT
  import Card from 'src/components/UIComponents/Cards/Card.vue'

  const tableColumns = [//some data]
  const tableData = [//some data]
  export default {
    components: {
      LTable,
      ETable, //THIS IS MY NEW COMPONENT
      Card
    },
    data () {
      return {
        //some data
      }
    },
  //some methods
  }
```

Of course the name tag in my new component is 'edit-table'.

There is happening other strange issue: when I change the name value in the component imported as 'LTable' it seems not to matter because everything keeps working good.

Please, any help is appreciated it.

Comment: try `components: {
      'l-table': LTable,
      'edit-table': ETable,
      'v-card': Card
    },`

Comment: ... or `import EditTable from 'src/components/UIComponents/Tables/EditableTable.vue'`. **Voting to close as a typo**

Comment: Please read the guide from this point and down ~ https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Component-Names

Comment: Also read about the component `name` property here ~ https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#name

Comment: @Sphinx it worked!! It is a shame anyway that I do not understand why this works. Could you or somebody else please explain me why this happen? Because as I concern, this is duplicating info, because inside each component the 'name' data is set.

Also thanks to Phil for sharing this documentation.

Comment: @DanielJaramillo from the second link I provided, the `name` attribute is used for two things only... 1) self-referencing the component (ie, recursive component rendering), and 2) defining the component name in dev-tools. It is **not** used when the component is imported into another.

Comment: @Phil. Very kind. Thanks.